# Turbo - NextJS unable to import files from Storybook defined as a package

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook, turborepo

I have the weirdest thing that has been happening to me for a few weeks now.

I have a turbo repo with a NextJS app as my main web app, and the UI defined in Storybook (defined as a turbo package).

The build command runs fine, but when I run turbo run dev (or yarn dev), my NextJS app is crashing because it cannot import any Storybook package.

That's the error I'm getting:

```
 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
[2] 
[2] Check your code at _app.tsx:35.
[2]     at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.tsx:51:18)
[2]     at StyleRegistry (/Users/louis-charles/Documents/Projects.nosync/mango3-front/src/node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/index/index.js:671:34)
[2]     at FlushEffectContainer (/Users/louis-charles/Documents/Projects.nosync/mango3-front/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:428:37)
[2]     at AppContainer (/Users/louis-charles/Documents/Projects.nosync/mango3-front/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:443:29)
[2]     at AppContainerWithIsomorphicFiberStructure (/Users/louis-charles/Documents/Projects.nosync/mango3-front/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:474:57)
[2]     at div
[2]     at Body (/Users/louis-charles/Documents/Projects.nosync/mango3-front/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:738:21)
```

It's not a problem of any import where I should have imported the components with curly braces, or any circular dependencies problem, because all the imports worked before I deleted the node_modules+yarn.lock files.

I tried running the yarn command to install the dependencies + turbo build + turbo dev, but when I run turbo dev the NextJS app is crashing.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I think it happens every time I run the yarn command from the NextJS app directory... I don't understand why this is the resulting behaviour...